# MongoDB 4.2.1 - updateMany: Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

So I have this issue with mongodb 4.2.1 using Robo 3T.
I want to update specific documents, by moving a field inside another one which is an object.

Using `update()` like this works fine.

```
db.getCollection('myCollections').update(
    {
        randomId: ObjectId("......."),
    },
    [
        { $set: { "myObject.myField": "$myField" } },
        { $unset: [ "myField" ] }
    ])
```

But when I want to update all my documents using `updateMany()` like this.

```
db.getCollection('myCollections').updateMany(
    {
        randomId: ObjectId("......."),
    },
    [
        { $set: { "myObject.myField": "$myField" } },
        { $unset: [ "myField" ] }
    ])
```

I have an error

```
Failed to execute script.

Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators 
Details:
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1
@(shell):1:1
```

I didn't try using the shell but I suppose it will tell me the same thing.

#### Edit

Example of a document before

```
{
  _id: ...,
  randomId: ObjectId(...),
  myField: 0.5
  myObject: {
    value1: 1,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

After

```
{
  _id: ...,
  randomId: ObjectId(...),
  myObject: {
    value1: 1,
    myField: 0.5,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My bad. I just tried with mongo shell and it works fine. Should stop using robo 3T for update.

Sorry for the bother and thanks for the answers

Comment: I had the same problem and it turns out this is a Studio 3T bug. Have you reported it by any chance?

Comment: Still buggy as of Robo 3T 1.3. Tried with mongo shell and works.

Comment: 1.3.1 - 2021 - still buggy

Comment: facing the same :(

Comment: That's not "your bad", that's a bug. Not your fault.

Comment: Seems to fixed in 1.4.3!

Answer (score 2):

Update the document using `$rename` *update operator*; it is just renaming the field.

```
db.upd.updateOne(
  { randomId: ObjectId("xyz")},
  { $rename: { myField: "myObject.myField" } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is to help people who did the same mistake of leaving **`$set`** like me.

So it gave me the same error message specified in the question.

Append **`$set` as well in the query.**

Before:

```
db.myData.updateOne({key:"value"},{key:"new-value"})
```

After:

```
db.myData.updateOne({key:"value"},{$set:{key:"new-value"}})
```

Then I was able to update my data.

Answer (score -1):

The second parameter of `updateOne()` and `updateMany()` must by an `Object`, so basically you are using a wrong syntax, try like this instead:

```
db.getCollection('myCollections').updateMany({
    randomId: ObjectId("......."),
}, {
    $set: {
        "myObject.myField": "$myField"
    },
    $unset: {
        "myField": 1
    }
})
```

Comment: So the update works fine but instead of `myField` value in `myObject.myField`, I have a string `$myField` for all updated documents.
For the second parameter of `updateMany`, I wanted to use aggregation pipeline like it was said in the docs, and you need to use this syntax: `[ <stage1>, ...  ]`.
Seems like the only way to get `myField` value is to use aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of understanding, but what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No problem :D. I just updated my question with some examples for what I want to do.