# Updating all fields of a mongodb collection with the value of the id field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a huge mongodb collection and want to update one of the fields to the value of the id field.

The syntax I am trying is the following:

```
db.getCollection("products").updateMany(
{},     
{  $set: { ProductId: "$_id" }  },  
{})
```

This, however, sets the value to the string "$_id". If I leave away the quotes, I get an error message:

> 2021-02-18T15:55:53.170+0100 E QUERY    [js] ReferenceError: $_id is not defined :

Comment: Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field) as well it has more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can achieve this in **MongoDB 4.2+**, actually second parameter needs to be wrapped in an array. (just learned something new)

```
db.getCollection("products").updateMany(
    {},
    [
        {  $set: { ProductId: "$_id" }  }
    ]
)
```

Comment: That is called an update with aggregation pipeline. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to Mongo DB, now thinking about how many queries I can improve at work. very excited to implement these tomorrow. haha

Comment: I have MongoDB version 4.4, but if I try to execute this command I get an error message:  E QUERY    [js] Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators :-( So this does not seem to be the solution so far.

Comment: @DavidElsner Have you tried it in mongo shell ?

Comment: No I am using studio 3T... I will update it. Maybe that fixes it.

Comment: It must be studio 3Ts problem. Like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58955143/mongodb-4-2-1-updatemany-error-the-update-operation-document-must-contain-at sorry...

Comment: Yes, I saw that earlier that is why I asked if you used it in shell, I tried it in shell directly worked like a charm.